# Insert data command not saving data into database in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have migrated a magento site successfully nut when i import database in phpmyadmin. it created all tables but not inserting all values in tables.
when i try to manually insert data.it does not save data and there in not error also..please help

Comment: I think that the file which you are trying to import is not successfully exported. Try to export the database file once again with the old database.

Comment: @PavanKumar thanks 4 the reply..bt file was succeccully exported...

Comment: @PavanKumar and even if i insert some data manully..it does not insert data and also not showing any error

Comment: Are you using PhpMyAdmin? Did you try to create another new database and import to it?

Comment: @PavanKumar yes i am using phpmyadmin..i created a new database and imported database but in that case it shows error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'link.area' in 'where clause'" when i reload my magento site

Comment: @PavanKumar when i reload magento site..it shows that error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'link.area' in 'where clause'" what does that mean??

Comment: is your magento application which you are trying to install contains the files of any extensions or any other modules?

Comment: @PavanKumar yes it contain files related to extensions

Comment: Then you cant install that magento application on empty database. What the error shows is the correct error only. I think there is a limit of creating databases in your server. Can you check it once and let me know.